# Why is my Bootstrap 4 Carousel is not working on Codeply?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the [carousel I am working on in Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/FoqNb3fN36). The slide will not advance or (slide) to the next slide, it remains fixed on the first yellow slide.
I try to preview it, same thing or color & alt text don't even show.

Please help..

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hmYm.png)

\

PLEASE NOTE: I am taking the Angela Yu Web Dev Bootcamp via Udemy & all is going well except for an issue I am experiencing when attempting to follow along with her Bootstrap Carousel.

**What I think the issue could be:**

1. I'm overlooking something small (extra div, missed tag, etc)
2. Wrong Bootstrap used in Codeply settings
3. Angela Yu video is slightly out of date (somethings have changed & the bootstrap she was using maybe diff now)

Comment: I would suggest going directly to bootstrap and see how they are doing it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: I checked the code and it matches the Bootstrap code. I am more concerned that it's my bootstrap framework I selected in settings that is causing the slides not to advance.

Comment: Can you share your code as text or SO snippet and not as image?

Comment: If everything else is correct then comment out other code until you find the conflict. You want to start as simple as possible to confirm it's working and then add back to it.

Comment: Thank you, for your feedback, I ended up redoing it and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well. I switched codeply bootstrap from 4 to 5 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Today on `18-June- 2022` while learning the same course, I have observed that the issue still persists.

After some research, when I have changed bootstrap version to `Bootstrap 4.6.0`, Carousel started working fine.

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: green;">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: blue;">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: yellow;">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel-item {
    height:500px;
}
```

**Frameworks**

```
Bootstrap 4.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use latest version of Bootstrap 5 i.e. 5.1.3
2. Change data-interval to data-bs-interval (it was changed after Bootstrap 4)
3. No need to put semicolon after the colors inside style ="background-color: green;"